# What feeds do we want in the chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-feed

In [the site's main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), there are bots posting all new questions from the [main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and the [meta site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Are the chat regulars happy with these bots, or would you prefer them to be removed? (No, making them post faster is not possible.)

Is there interest in having the bots post questions with “interesting” tags from other sites? I'm thinking of `[science-fiction]`, `[fantasy]`, and `[horror]` on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), and maybe [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/). All of these sites are low-traffic compared to us; there'd be less than 1 per day on average altogether.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like the feeds in the chat. I've noticed that when I ask a question it's not until it hits the chat that I see people reading it. If the feature were removed, I feel like my exposure would be limited.

I also think it would be awesome if we could get some cross promotion from Lit and Movie. If you added them to our chat feed as well, it would boost their view count tremendously I think.

Comment: I'd like to note that, if one does *not* like the feeds in chat, you can ignore the bot and the posts will disappear from the room when you're logged in.

Answer (score 4):

**Suggestions** - feel free to add/edit/remove any:

- [the-hobbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit)
- [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)
- [the-matrix](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-matrix)
- [star-trek-into-darkness](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-into-darkness), [star-trek-next-generation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-next-generation), [star-trek-tos](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos), [star-trek-first-contact](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-first-contact), [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan), [star-trek-voyager](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager), [star-trek-2009](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009) -- most of these have at least one question not tagged with star-trek
- Alternately [star-trek-*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-*) if it works technologically (suggestion by Keen)
- [doctor-who](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who)
- [the-dark-knight-rises](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-knight-rises) - a big tag, and only half covered by batman
- [batman-begins or the-dark-knight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-begins+or+the-dark-knight)
- [inception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inception) - another big one
- [the-avengers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-avengers) - 50 questions, of which only 7 are tagged marvel-cinematic-universe
- [avengers-age-of-ultron](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-age-of-ultron)
- <strike>[x-men*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men*) - 44 questions all together</strike>
- [the-wolverine](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-wolverine)
- [the-terminator or terminator-*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-2+or+terminator-genisys+or+the-terminator+or+terminator-salvation+or+terminator-3) (currently 5 tags)
- [time-travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) - wow! 44 questions
- [back-to-the-future](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-to-the-future)
- [men-in-black-3 or men-in-black](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-in-black-3+or+men-in-black)
- [avatar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar)
- [avatar-the-last-airbender](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender)
- [x-men-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe) (count 105)
- [arrowverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse) (count: 75)
- [lucifer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) (count: 7)

Comment: a vote from me against despicable me. just because it's on topic here doesn't mean we need all of their questions. as it stands, M/TV only has 5 despicable me questions right now. i'd rather use the slot for something at least moderately used.

Comment: I know it's a lot of tags, but I think it may be managable if I filtered the rss with an off-site script.

Comment: Any reason why Star Wars isn't there?

Comment: @Rogue Yes: no one has suggested it yet.

Comment: just added 3 and have so many in mind, might write them later

Comment: The whole thing is rather outdated. *Everything* MCU is already tagged `marvel-cinematic-universe`, *everything* *Star Trek* is already tagged `star-trek`.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach I did thought to strike all the not needed ones but it's way outdated that i am thinking to add a new answer instead sometime in future

Answer (score -3):

I like the Bots but would enjoy more fantasy posts and book posts being posted. There is far more sci-fi stuff and movie stuff then books and fantasy.

Comment: I think the question was looking for specific tags to add

Comment: Well then add the tags that would bring those elements in?

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer. Currently *all* new questions on SFF are piped into Mos Eisley, fantasy and sci-fi alike. The CW answer above is talking about which tags from *Movies & TV* to pipe into Mos, which of course won't help the goal of more fantasy book posts.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The OP didn't say anything about Movies and Tv just what tags you wanted to see more of from other places... But I get your point :) But wait this was posted four years ago... why are we talking about it now?

Comment: *"In the site's main chat room, there are bots posting all new questions from the main site and the meta site. [...] Is there interest in having the bots post questions with “interesting” tags from other sites?"* - (And unfortunately, the Literature site is dead.)

Comment: @Rincewind I don't know, why are we talking about it now? You're the one who just posted a new answer here! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor oops...?